# How to find all invisible cell from uicollection view?

Tags: ios

How to find all invisible cell from UICollection view?

In my application i am set Timer to all cell. But I am trying to make cell nil when cells are invisible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that CollectionView on iOS, as all lists, recycle its cells to use the least possible memory (see `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`).

So, when a cell become invisible (certainly because the collection view is scrolling), it will go to the reusable queue and will soon be re-used for a newly visible cell because the collection view is scrolling.

When the collection view need to display a newly viisble view, it will call `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`on its `dataSource`. In this method that you have to override, you first call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to have a reusable cell instead of creating a new one.

If one previous cell is available, you should stop its timer and restart a new one for its new content.

Else, you can manage a global list of timers on your controller, associated to their `IndexPath`, and when the timer fires, verify of its associated `IndexPath` is still displayed using `indexPathsForVisibleItems`.

Answer (score 4):

i would go about this in a different way, probably. If you want the cells to animate, you could set a property `shouldAnimate = YES`. Then in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` check that property and apply the animation if needed (or remove it).

After setting the property, reload only the visibleCells:

```
 [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems].
```

Now, since the animation is provided when a cell is requested through the Datasource-Protocol, you also get the animation when you scroll.